# Is there a plastic bowl/dish that can withstand high temperature in the oven?

Tags: baking, equipment

I am looking for a plastic bowl or dish that can withstand high temperature in the oven? A bowl or dish that won't melt nor emit odour. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Never saw one.  Googling for heat-resistant plastic bowls, pans etc did not provide me with any kitchenware that is both heat-resistant and plastic.  Why won't metal, oven-capable glass or silicone bowls do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [flexible food grade plastics that won't melt at 105 C](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21537/flexible-food-grade-plastics-that-wont-melt-at-105-c)

Comment: Can you explain why you're looking for such an item?  I'd be tempted to point you towards silicone bowls, but I don't know why you're specifically asking about plastic.  I suspect resin bowls could take the temperature (especially those that are cured w/ heat), but I don't know if they're food safe when heated (I've only seen them for pet dishes, not for humans)

Comment: @Mien: The questions do seem similar, but the other one is looking for gasketting, not bakeware, and they're talking about temperatures a little above boiling, not full oven temp.

Comment: i'm not sure about the shape your looking for but take a look at the high heat cambro boxes, they are rated to 500F I think.

Answer (score 5):

Silicone bakeware is available which is oven safe up to 500°F/260°C. Just like other materials it has some advantages and disadvantages.

**Advantages:**

- Easy to clean rubbery surface (will need a little cooking spray, but not much)
- Flexible, so easier to remove baked goods
- Often fridge/microwave safe

**Disadvantages:**

- Not very durable, due to softer material
- Can be cut by metal utensils
- Floppy
- May warp or melt in some cases.

Generally, I've heard very mixed reviews from bakers using silicone (except for Silpats). Although you can obtain it in the American market, most people prefer metal or Pyrex.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As already mentioned, silicone is rated to about 500°F

Aside from PTFE (teflon), the other commonly available plastic rated for oven temps is CPET, usuually used for disposable bakeware.  Examples of CPET plastic oven-safe bakeware:

- [Gladware 9x12](http://glad.com/food-storage/containers/ovenware-9x12/)
- [Ovenready Bakery Tray](http://genpak.com/product/oven-ready-bakery-trays/)
- [Ovenready Food Tray](http://genpak.com/product/oven-ready-food-trays/)
- [Overready Plastic Bakeware at Web Restaurant Store](http://webstaurantstore.com/391/oven-ready-plastic-bakeware.html)

Answer (score 1):

A few hard plastics are oven safe. Le Creuset says that the covers of their enamelled Dutch ovens [are safe up to 190°C](http://www.lecreuset.de/Produkte-/Gusseisen/Klassische-Brater/Brater-Tradition-rund-20cm/). Their knobs are made from some kind of phenolic compound. Bakelite can also be heated a lot and does not melt, although I am not sure if it is food safe.

Still, I have never heard of bowls made from these plastics, nor other plastic bowls made for the oven. And I don't think there will be any. The advantages of plastic are that it is lightweight, cheap, can be colored beautifully, and doesn't break easily. Phenolic plastics don't have any of these - they are difficult to produce, cost a lot, they are dense (so they are heavy for their size), they tend to be hard to color (bakelite is always darkish, and gets darker with time), and they are brittle in comparison to other plastics. Still, these things have all the disadvantages of plastic. They can never go to temperatures as high as other materials, and some of them can contain nasty chemicals you don't want anywhere near your food.

No matter what you need this bowl for, there is a better solution than plastic. Depending on what you want, steel can give you the lightness and unbreakability, and glass or ceramics can give you the thermal insulation properties you could get with plastic.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there are high temperature plastic cooking utensils, very many in fact.  I'm not clear on what your intended use is, but here is a rundown.

There are two general types, hard high temp plastic and silicone.  The hard plastic is typically rated to withstand oven heat up to 410F (210C), and they are not for stove top or broiler use due to much higher heat.  Silicone plastic utensils withstand up to 500F, but again, no stove top or broiler use.  Both can be used in microwave ovens, their primary use. I use both kinds for baking, and the hard for roasting.

The hard plastic utensils are fine for baking standard cakes, typically at $350F, and as roasting racks for non-broiler use.  There are simple cake pans, cupcake pans, bundt pans as well as the roasting racks for meats.  The work well, may darken with age.  Nordic Ware, Anchor Hocking and many others make high quality hard high-temp plastic utensils.

Silicone utensils are not rigid but can be stiff enough with ribbing.  One advantage is that they can be easily molded into a vast number of shapes.  They tend to release food easily, another plus.  They are very inexpensive compared to metal utensils.  It is best to buy a known brand, like Wilton, since a vast number of them are cheap imports that are too flimsy or won't stand much heat.

Answer (score 1):

Nordic Ware has plates which are durable and safe in the oven to a temperature of 400F. You can purchase them on [Walmart's Website](http://www.wasserstrom.com/restaurant-supplies-equipment/Product_6011288?kwid=productads-plaid%5E77644621244-sku%5E6011288-adType%5EPLA-device%5Ec-adid%5E45649633484) or [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G49AZCE).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it exists!

Clean Baking Products is a company, specialized in baking moulds made off the best, innovative composite material.

This material can resist temperatures from - 40°C till 250°C.

Advantages:

- - 40°C - 250°C
- for the oven
- no oxidation
- no deformation
- light-weight
- less use of butter

Check out for more information: www.cleanbakingproducts.com